# Support library version specification

Tags: android-studio, android-support-library

What is the support library version for `compileSdkVersion24` ?
i was using these support libraries.

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
```

after updating sdk, i tried changing the support version from `23.1.1` to `24.1.1`. it says,

> failed to resolve com.android.support:design:24.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Android Support Library,recommend version is 24.0.0

so change this

```
com.android.support:design:24.1.1
```

to this

```
com.android.support:design:24.0.0
```

Comment: @user3259671 glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

24.0.0 Android studio should recommend this.